# How to Write the Where Condition in Select Statement of dynamic Column Creation in Pivot

Tags: .net, pivot

Here How to Write the Where Condtion here i want Select only Particular Exam ID location
Mentioned below

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000);
    SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                                    '],[' + t2.PartID
                            FROM    StudentAnswer AS t2
                            ORDER BY '],[' + t2.PartID
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @Query= N' SELECT ExamID,StudentID,'+@cols+'
    FROM 
    (SELECT   StudentID,PartID,ExamID
                      , CASE WHEN Ans=CorrectAns THEN 1 WHEN Ans!=CorrectAns THEN 0 END as Result
              FROM StudentAnswer  **//Where Condtion**
            ) p 
             PIVOT ( SUM(Result)
                        FOR PartID 
                          IN ('+@cols+')
                      )  AS pvt;'
    EXECUTE(@Query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the Answer by Using this..

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000);
    SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                                    '],[' + t2.PartID
                            FROM    StudentAnswer AS t2
                            ORDER BY '],[' + t2.PartID
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @Query= N' SELECT ExamID,StudentID,'+@cols+'
    FROM 
    (SELECT   StudentID,PartID,ExamID
                      , CASE WHEN Ans=CorrectAns THEN 1 WHEN Ans!=CorrectAns THEN 0 END as Result
              FROM StudentAnswer WHERE ExamID=''EX201411E1''**// Here Use the tow single Qutation**``
            ) p 
             PIVOT ( SUM(Result)
                        FOR PartID 
                          IN ('+@cols+')
                      )AS pvt;'                    
    EXECUTE(@Query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Just do it ........

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000);
SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                                '],[' + t2.PartID
                        FROM    StudentAnswer AS t2
                        ORDER BY '],[' + t2.PartID
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @Query= N' SELECT ExamID,StudentID,'+@cols+'
FROM 
(SELECT   StudentID,PartID,ExamID
                  , CASE WHEN Ans=CorrectAns THEN 1 WHEN Ans!=CorrectAns THEN 0 END as Result
          FROM StudentAnswer  Where ExamID = yourExamID
        ) p 
         PIVOT ( SUM(Result)
                    FOR PartID 
                      IN ('+@cols+')
                  )  AS pvt;'
EXECUTE(@Query);
```

If you have any problem with that please mention also include more detail of your problem as well as output......